# SQL Server split field and create addition rows with values from main row

Tags: sql-server, split

I have a table with rows and in one field there are values like this A,B,C

Table 'Mytable':

```
|ID | Date       | MyValue | SplitID |
|1  | 2019-12-17 | A       |         |
|2  | 2019-12-15 | A,B     |         |
|3  | 2019-12-16 | B,C     |         |
```

Result should be:

```
|1 | 2019-12-17 | A | 1 |
|2 | 2019-12-15 | A | 2 |
|4 | 2019-12-15 | B | 2 |
|3 | 2019-12-16 | B | 3 |
|5 | 2019-12-16 | C | 3 |
```

(Sorry, I could not find HOW to format a table in the Stackoverflow help)

I tried a inline table function which splits the Field Myvalue into more lines but could not pass my rows with

```
charindex(',',[MyValue])>0
```

from MyTable as input lines.

The code is this:

```
ALTER function [dbo].[fncSplitString](@input Varchar(max), @Splitter Varchar(99), @ID int) 
returns table as
Return
with tmp (DataItem, ix, ID) as
( select LTRIM(@input)  , CHARINDEX('',@Input), @ID  --Recu. start, ignored val to get the types right
 union all
 select LTRIM(Substring(@input, ix+1,ix2-ix-1)), ix2, @ID
 from (Select *, CHARINDEX(@Splitter,@Input+@Splitter,ix+1) ix2 from tmp) x where ix2<>0
) select DataItem,ID from tmp where ix<>0
```

Thanks for help

Michael

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: Is ordinal position important?

Comment: SQL Server 2012; no ordinal position is not important, I just need to add the "original ID" into the field "SplitID" to follow up the ID (PK).

Comment: @Zhorov: how did you format my table???

Comment: You can use this for writing beautiful tables: https://senseful.github.io/text-table/

Comment: *Sorry, I could not find HOW to format a table in the Stackoverflow help*: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Duplicate and Split Row based on value by using SQL Query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55167886/duplicate-and-split-row-based-on-value-by-using-sql-query)

Comment: @mak The table is formatted as `code sample` (using `{}`).

Comment: @mak Request you to check my answer with demo given.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query.

```
Create table #Temp(
Id int,
DateField Date,
MyValue Varchar(10),
SplitID int
)

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitPra] (@Value VARCHAR(MAX), @delimiter CHAR)  
RETURNS @DataResult TABLE([Position] TINYINT IDENTITY(1,1),[Value] NVARCHAR(128))  
AS  
BEGIN  
DECLARE @XML xml = N'<r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(@Value, @delimiter, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r>'  
INSERT INTO @DataResult ([Value])  
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(T.c.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(128)')))  
FROM @xml.nodes('//r') T(c)  
RETURN  
END  

insert into #Temp Values(1, '2019-12-17', 'A', NULL),(2, '2019-12-15', 'A,B', NULL), (3, '2019-12-16', 'B,C', NULL)

Select 
    #Temp.Id, DateField, b.Value as MyValue, b.Id as SplitValue 
from #Temp inner join (
select 
    Id, f.* 
from 
    #Temp u
    cross apply [dbo].[SplitPra](u.MyValue, ',') f   
)b on #Temp.Id = b.Id

Drop table #Temp
```

This will give an output as shown below.

```
Id  DateField   MyValue SplitValue
---------------------------------
1   2019-12-17  A       1
2   2019-12-15  A       2
2   2019-12-15  B       2
3   2019-12-16  B       3
3   2019-12-16  C       3
```

You can find the live demo [here](https://rextester.com/NWZF40826).

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution, i hope it will work for you. But i didn't use your function to solve this problem. **Instead of that, i used cross apply function**.You can find the query below:

```
-- Creating Test Table

CREATE TABLE #Test
(
    ID int,
    Date date,
    MyValue nvarchar(max),
    SplitID int
);
GO

-- Inserting data into test table

INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (1, '2019-12-17', 'A', NULL);
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (2, '2019-12-15', 'A,B', NULL);
INSERT INTO #Test VALUES (3, '2019-12-16', 'B,C', NULL);
GO

-- Select query

SELECT
*,
(SELECT ID FROM test t1 WHERE t.Date = t1.date) AS SplitID
FROM
(
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS ID,
    Date,
    substring(A.value,1,
    CASE WHEN charindex(',',rtrim(ltrim(A.value))) = 0 then LEN(A.value)
    ELSE charindex(',',rtrim(ltrim(A.value))) -1 end) as MyValue
FROM Test
CROSS APPLY string_split (MyValue, ',') A) AS T
ORDER BY MyValue ASC;
```

And the result must be like that:

```
ID  Date        MyValue SplitID
1   2019-12-17  A       1
2   2019-12-15  A       2
3   2019-12-15  B       2
4   2019-12-16  B       3
5   2019-12-16  C       3
```